# How to map enums using Value Injector

Tags: c#, enums, valueinjecter

I am trying to get my hands on ValueInjector having used Automapper in the past. I want to convert one enum to another where only the enum names are different but the property name and values are same.

```
 public enum GenderModel
    {
        NotSpecified = 0,
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2
    }

public enum GenderDto
    {
        NotSpecified = 0,
        Male = 1,
        Female = 2
    }
```

Then I am trying to map like this

```
var model = GenderModel.Male;
            var dto = GenderDto.NotSpecified;
            dto.InjectFrom(model);
```

I am expecting to get Male in dto object but it is still set to NotSpecified.

What am I missing? Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, `ValueInjecter` can not map value types such as `enum, struct, int, double`. Or no need map for value types. It only help to map class types' properties that have same name and type. To map enum for this example, I suggest,

```
    var model = GenderModel.Male;
    var dto = GenderDto.NotSpecified;
    dto = (GenderDto)model;
```

If the enum is nested in the specific class, the default ValueInjecter can not map `GenderModel` and `GenderDto` because they are different type. So we can implement it by a customer ValueInjecter. This is my test code here, hope it can help.

```
public enum GenderModel
{
    NotSpecified = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

public enum GenderDto
{
    NotSpecified = 0,
    Male = 1,
    Female = 2
}

public class Person1
{
    public GenderModel Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Person2
{
    public GenderDto Gender { get; set; }
}

public class EnumMapInjection:IValueInjection
{
    public object Map(object source, object target)
    {
        StaticValueInjecter.DefaultInjection.Map(source, target);
        if (target is Person2 && source is Person1)
        {
            ((Person2) target).Gender = (GenderDto)((Person1) source).Gender;
        }
        return target;
    }
}
```

And the Main function code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var person1 = new Person1(){Gender = GenderModel.Male};
        var person2 = new Person2(){Gender = GenderDto.Female};
        person2.InjectFrom<EnumMapInjection>(person1); 
    }
```

Comment: Yes but imagine if this Enum is nested in a Person Class and I am getting a list of person and want to map them to a list of DTO. Unless I can define mapping using ValueInjecter, I would need to iterate list and map the enums manually.

Comment: In this case, I suggest a customer Injection inherit from IValueInjection. I can give you an example in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Type casting is your solution

```
dto = (GenderDto)model;
```